# Can we use NSFileManager in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I need to use the NSFileManager class in my own iPhone app...Before that I would like to know whether it would be supported in iPhone???Can anyone help me???

Thanks in advance,

Syam

Answer (score 3):

It's supported. Its one of the main ways to open and save files that are outside the app bundle